Is there a way in C# to override the 8000 byte limit when using SQLDataReader.GetBytes?
I have a database that has file data stored in an image column. I need to be able to extract the data in this image column and create a document on disk.
I am using C# to run the queries, extract the data and create the images on disk. In this instance I have a tif file stored in the database. I am using SqlDataReader to get get the data from my SQL query.
The issue I have is that SqlDataReader.GetBytes is only returning the first 8000 bytes. I have thousands of images with varying sizes. Is there anyway to override this 8000 byte limit?
This is my code:
byte[] byteArray = new byte[57470];

using (sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlConn))
{
    sqlDataRead = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (sqlDataRead.Read())
    {
        long lngNumBytes = sqlDataRead.GetBytes(sqlDataRead.GetOrdinal("attachment_data"), byteArray, 57470);
    }
}


your call to GetBytes seems to be missing some Parameters.  You are likely getting an incorrect output due to these missing values.  you should be passing public override long GetBytes (int i, long dataIndex, byte[] buffer, int bufferIndex, int length);, but you are only passing 3 values.  if you are trying to read the entire buffer, you probably need to pass 0 for both dataIndex and bufferIndex.  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes

Which Net-Framework do you use? Propably you should use EntityFramework or Linq2Sql to get your Data

SqlClient Streaming Support

Also look at Binary Large Object (Blob) Data (SQL Server)

@ChrisBerlin I am using Microsoft .NET Core Runtime 3.1.30, Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.1.426 and Microsoft .NET Runtime - 6.0.29.  I am developing my code in Visual Studio.

@AlexanderPetrov Thank you for the Streaming info.  Unfortunately I am still getting limited to 8000 bytes. I have tried looking for any and all settings they may cause this.

Your .NET version is end-of-life more than two years ago, but that shouldn't cause this.

The image data type has been deprecated a long time ago, and will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use varbinary(max) instead. See details here

I have figured out my issue. I was sub-stringing the image field to just get the bytes that contained them image data, not any header information.  When I switched to just use the image field I get all the data.  I will parse the image data in my program.

Your problem is elsewhere.  GetBytes is capable of returning more than 8000 bytes.  Try this:
var constr = $"Server=localhost;database=tempdb;Integrated Security=true;trustservercertificate=true";

using var conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
conn.Open();

var sql = @"
with q as 
(
select cast(replicate(cast(N'x' as nvarchar(max)),100000)  as varbinary(max)) b
)
select b attachment_data, DATALENGTH(b) length
from q
";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);   

using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[200000];
        long lngNumBytes = rdr.GetBytes(0,0, byteArray,0, 200000);
        Console.WriteLine($"Read {lngNumBytes} bytes");
    }

}

outputs
Read 200000 bytes

You need to look at your query and the table to find where the data is being truncated to 8000 bytes.
